# Mod Rewrite - WP url &preview_nonce=(.*)

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I would like to change any url containing the query string `&preview_nonce=` with any value passed to `preview_nonce`.

I understand that I have to rewrite based on the condition:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^preview_nonce=(.*)$`

But I'm getting caught up only removing that from the query string and leaving everything else, including query strings.

Example URLs:

```
about-us/history/commitment/?preview=true&preview_id=9999&preview_nonce=9x323k1
stories/companies/?preview=true&preview_id=8888&preview_nonce=c448s88
```

The desired results:

```
about-us/history/commitment/?preview=true&preview_id=9999
stories/companies/?preview=true&preview_id=8888
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule for query string removal:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?preview_nonce=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Make sure this rule is placed before other WP rules.

Comment: This causes a 500 error: `RewriteCond: unknown flag 'L'`

Comment: sorry there was a typo, fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, this works in your context! But what I was wondering was how to consider all URLS with `?preview=true?preview_id=(.*)&preview_nonce=(.*)`, disregarding anything before it like `about-us/history/commitment/`?? I tried removing that part but it didn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it with `^(.*)?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,NC,R=302]`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For some reason `/blockquotes/?preview=true&preview_id=33333&preview_nonce=x77s1293` isn't getting rewritten. Any idea??

Comment: That URI `/blockquotes/?preview=true&preview_id=33333&preview_nonce=x77s1293` worked in my testing

Comment: My apologies, I must have had a typo that wasn't throwing an error. Thank you for all of your help, anubhava